# Syntax to add a row in a table using jquery where there are a URL and apostrophes in the field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Syntax to add a row in a table using jquery where there are a URL and apostrophes

Hi guys, I'm working in a table where you can add dynamically the rows in a table using jquery, the first row of my table [row0] is in the page with html5 code and there is a script that I use to add other rows, one of the fields has a button where I need to click to open a small window like you can see in the next image:

The table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qP9s.jpg

The window when I clicked in the button of the first row:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXZom.jpg

My problem begins when I try to add the others rows, my script add the rows, but I don't know how can I add the button with the URL because when I use the URL into the jquery code I can't open the window

The code of the button inside the body [row0]

```
<td>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name='responsable0' id="responsable0" placeholder='' class="form-control" disabled=""/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-user" href="/Riesgos_seleccionarResponsable.asp?nombre=responsable0&amp;registro=registro0" onclick="window.open('Riesgos_seleccionarResponsable.asp?nombre=responsable0&amp;registro=registro0','targetWindow','toolbar=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=600, height=500');return false;"></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</td>
```

The code of my jquery script [rowN](at the moment I only can open a new blank tab)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
              var i=1;

             $("#agregarAccionA").click(function(){
              $('#amenaza'+0+'accion'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='accion"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control input-md'/></td> <td><input name='fechaFin"+i+"' type='date' placeholder=''  class='form-control input-md'></td> <td><div class='input-group'><input type='text' name='responsable"+i+"' id='responsable"+i+"' placeholder='' class='form-control' disabled=''/><span class='input-group-btn'><button type='button' class='btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-user' href='Riesgos_seleccionarResponsable.asp?nombre=responsable0&amp;registro=registro0' onclick='window.open();return false;'></button></span></div></td> <td><input name='descripcion"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control input-md'></td> <td><select name='estado"+i+"' class='form-control'><option selected disabled value=''>Seleccione el estado</option><option>No iniciado</option><option>En proceso</option><option>Cumplido</option></select></td> <td><select name='tipoAccion"+i+"' class='form-control'><option selected disabled value=''>Seleccione la acción</option><option>Monitoreo</option><option>Mitigación</option><option>Solución definitiva</option></select></td>");

              $('#acciones').append('<tr id="amenaza'+(0)+'accion'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
              i++;
          });

             $("#eliminarAccionA").click(function(){
                 if(i>1){
                 $("#amenaza"+(0)+"accion"+(i-1)).html('');
                 i--;
                 }
             });

        });

    </script>
```

I need to add this to the window.open() in my jquery code, how can I do it?

```
'Riesgos_seleccionarResponsable.asp?nombre=responsable0&amp;registro=registro0','targetWindow','toolbar=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=600, height=500'
```

Thanks for your help!

**Update**

I have identified more about my problem, watch this:

[The code of the button for the row0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU9i6.jpg)

[The code of the button that it's added with jquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yujgd.jpg)

I rewrite my code of the button added with jquery letter for letter because I saw some strange characters multiple times in the middle of the window.open statement ("& z w n j ; & # 8 2 0 3" <-- this without spaces), probably they were there because I use SublimeText and SublimeText always completes the quotation mark, but I'm not sure. I don't have strange characters now, but if you can see in my code the quatation marks is incorrect for the link. Again my code here:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
              var i=1;

             $("#agregarAccionC").click(function(){
              $('#amenaza'+0+'accion'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='accion"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control input-md'/></td> <td><input name='fechaFin"+i+"' type='date' placeholder='' class='form-control input-md'></td> <td><div class='input-group'><input type='text' name='responsable"+i+"' id='responsable"+i+"' placeholder='' class='form-control' disabled=''/><span class='input-group-btn'><button type='button' class='btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-user' href='/Riesgos_seleccionarResponsable.asp?nombre=responsable0&amp;registro=registro0' onClick='window.open('Riesgos_seleccionarResponsable.asp?nombre=responsable0&amp;registro=registro0','targetWindow','toolbar=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=600, height=500');return false;'></button></span></div></td> <td><input name='descripcion"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control input-md'></td> <td><select name='estado"+i+"' class='form-control'><option selected disabled value=''>Seleccione el estado</option><option>No iniciado</option><option>En proceso</option><option>Cumplido</option></select></td><td><select name='tipoAccion"+i+"' class='form-control'><option selected disabled value=''>Seleccione la acción</option><option>Monitoreo</option><option>Mitigación</option><option>Solución definitiva</option></select></td>");

              $('#acciones').append('<tr id="amenaza'+(0)+'accion'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
              i++;
          });

             $("#eliminarAccionC").click(function(){
                 if(i>1){
                 $("#amenaza"+(0)+"accion"+(i-1)).html('');
                 i--;
                 }
             });

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: So, why can you not put that code inside the brackets of `window.open()`? You have a lot of code with apostrophes already in your code and if that is no problem, then I don't see, why it should be a problem to put it into the brackets.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, are you saying that I need to write: `onclick='window.open('Riesgos_seleccionarResponsable.asp?nombre=responsable0&amp;registro=registro0','targetWindow','toolbar=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=600, height=500');`

Comment: That is what I would try and see what the result is.

Comment: I had tried that but it didn't work for me, I don't know if the problem is with the use of the apostrophe and I need to use the backslahs () or write the text in other way. If I have empty window.open() I can open a blank window in a new tab, but If I use the url inside I can't open it.